# jqgrid- applying multiple themes to multiple table in the same page

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have 2 jqgrid tables here in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/exw6hug9/), what is the best way to apply multiple themes only to the jqgrid tables.

I had tried adding css selector scope to the tables but it didnt work correctly on the table  http://jqueryui.com/download/

Theme1 for table1

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../themeLefrog/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../themeLefrog/jquery-ui.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../themeLefrog/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
```

My theme2 for table2

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../themeBlitzer/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../themeBlitzer/jquery-ui.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../themeBlitzer/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should download custom jQuery UI themes from [the jQuery UI download page](http://jqueryui.com/download/). For example, you want to use Le-Frog and Redmond themes on one HTML page. The you can use HTML code like

```html
<div class="redmond">
    <table id="grid1"></table>
</div>
<div class="le-frog">
    <table id="grid2"></table>
</div>
```

It means that `div.redmond` and `div.le-frog` could be selectors, which could be used to specify the scope of applying of the corresponding jQuery UI Theme CSS. Thus you can choose the following on the download page:

[image]
[image]

You included both CSS on your web page, like

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/le-frog/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
```

and use the same code as usual. The results will be like on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1-scope.htm):

[image]

or like on [the another demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1-scope1.htm), which use Blitzer and Le-Frog themes:

[image]

I included in the demos `jquery-ui.css` instead of `jquery-ui.min.css` only to simplify everybody to examine the files. There contains CSS rules with the corresponding rules. For example

```css
div.redmond .ui-widget {
    font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

and

```css
div.le-frog .ui-widget {
    font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

instead of the standard rule

```css
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detail answer Thanks